# Json.Decode in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, decode, asp.net-mvc-5

```
var searchModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.schoolSearch));
```

Above code successfully encodes Model.schoolSearch to searchModel.

How can I get reverse?
I have json as a string I need to encode it as Model.schoolSearch

I have tried:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Decode(jsonText, Model.schoolSearch));
```

and

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Decode<Model.schoolSearch>(jsonText));
```

But not working.

Comment: Define "not working". Does it compile? Any errors/warnings?

Comment: Why is this tagged Javascript?

Comment: i am trying this in view side. I need to get value of model inside js code.